# How to configure static Private Address in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a requirement where I want to manage 3 instances in a VPC holding my applications having different functionality which are not public facing instances. At some point in time for managing the unnecessary instances usage, I would like to stop 2 of my instances and restart those instances when required.

- When I restart my instance I am getting a new private address which is causing my application to fail without running.
- I can't assign Elastic IP as it is not a public facing instance
- I don't want to reconfigure it every time I stop and start the instance.

Any help is apprecated.

Comment: This is very strange. The Private IP Address for an instance should never change. (The Public one can change, but not the Private one.)

Answer (score 6):

You can assign multiple private IP-addresses within your EC2 instance. The first IP is always auto-assigned by AWS. The second IP, on the other hand, can be static and defined by your environment.

For a more complete explanation on how to enable such a setup, I recommend the AWS documentation in multiple IP addresses.

[Multiple IP Addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html)

Comment: *"The first IP is always auto-assigned by AWS"* is not (always) correct.  You can specify a static address in the launch request as long as you are submitting a [`RunInstances`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html) request for a *single* instance, not multiple instances.  This works on the API and in the console.

Answer (score 5):

When launching a new instance you can manually define the private IP address you'd like to use.

To do this, on the 'Configure Instance Details' screen of the wizard, manually select a subnet to launch in, and then in the 'Network Interfaces' section that appears enter the private IP address you wish to use.

Reference [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=222861)